# How to use an Emoji font with Blender?

Tags: text-object

Here are some Emoji:

http://getemoji.com/

These Emoji can be easily copy/pasted into Microsoft Word on Windows.

I am encountering a world of hurt by trying to get any of these to work with Blender.

Comment: You can start with large screen shots from your text editor, vector trace them in Inkscape, then import the SVGs into Blender.

Answer (score 0):

To use an Emoji font in Blender as a font, first one must have the font installed on the computer. Do a search, using your favorite search engine for "emoji font", appending either "ttf" or "unicode" according to your preference, and download and install one of the fonts you locate by that method to your computer, as you would any other font. Now, the font should be accessible in Blender in the same way any other installed ~.ttf or ~.unicode font is accessible.

If you don't know how to have Blender make use of the installed fonts on your computer, [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTk6oMvP1eU) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Change the font - the only font working for me is the pre-installed `Segoe UI Emoji Regular`.